# Does linearity apply for infinite summation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

In linear algebra, we know that for every linear operator, if we know where the basis elements are mapped to, we know where every element is mapped to by linearity. Now I wondering if linearity applies for infinite sums over infinite dimensional space. Basically, it is true that $f(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...)=a_1f(x_1)+a_2f(x_2)+...$ for infinite summations and if not, what are the requirements for this to be the case?

Now for a more specific example, let us take the $l^p$ sequence space for $1<p<\infty$ and take the cannonical "basis" $(e^m)$ where $(e^m_n)$ is $0$ for $n=m$ and $0$ otherwise. Now I know this is not an actual basis, because in a Banach space, the basis is either finite or uncountable. But even if that is the case, if infinite linearity applies, then if we know where each $(e^m)$ is mapped to, that still gives us enough information to know where every elements of $l^p$ is mapped to.

Comment: an infinite sum is really a _limit_ of finite sums $\sum a_i x_i = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{N} a_i x_i$. So you're asking when $\lim_{N \to \infty} f \left ( \sum_N a_i x_i \right ) = f \left ( \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_N a_i x_i \right )$. But this is exactly what it means for $f$ to be continuous (often called [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) in this setting)

Comment: if we have a linear map $f$, then for infinite sums $\sum_na_n$ we have $f(\sum_na_n)=\sum_nf(a_n)$ iff $f$ is continuous

Comment: In a general vector space it is not even clear what an infinite sum is. Remember that we understand $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k:=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^N a_k$. So, infinite sums only make sense if we have some structure that allows to talk about limits.

Comment: The "infinite sums over infinite dimensional spaces" would need to be defined.  A vector space only provides for sums of two vectors, from which finite sums are determined.   This is a limitation of sums even when a vector space is infinite dimensional.   One might make a definition like for formal power series that supports *linearity*, but the "infinite summation" then is merely a matter of notation, not tied to convergence.